# Framed Background and ImageMargins

Tags: plotting

I want to make some description on my plots, but I can't make it good.

First I tried this:

```
Plot[Sin[100 x], {x, 0, 50}, PlotStyle -> Black, 
 Epilog -> 
  Inset[Framed[Style[111, 30, Red], FrameStyle -> Red, 
    Background -> Directive[White, Opacity[0.5]]], {25, 0}, {Center, 
    Bottom}], AxesStyle -> Red]
```

[image]

But I need some margins, so I did it:

```
Plot[Sin[100 x], {x, 0, 50}, PlotStyle -> Black, 
 Epilog -> 
  Inset[Framed[Style[111, 30, Red], FrameStyle -> Red, 
    Background -> Directive[White, Opacity[0.5]], 
    ImageMargins -> 5], {25, 0}, {Center, Bottom}], AxesStyle -> Red]
```

[image]

But where is my background??? I don't understand what's wrong. OK. I tried this:

```
Plot[Sin[100 x], {x, 0, 50}, PlotStyle -> Black, 
 Epilog -> 
  Inset[Framed[Style[111, 30, Red], FrameStyle -> Red, 
    ImageMargins -> 5], {25, 0}, {Center, Bottom}, 
   Background -> Directive[White, Opacity[0.5]]], AxesStyle -> Red]
```

[image]

Ands it's not that I want. I need margins without background. So I make a stupid thing, I added one Framed more:

```
Plot[Sin[100 x], {x, 0, 50}, PlotStyle -> Black, 
 Epilog -> 
  Inset[Framed[
    Framed[Style[111, 30, Red], FrameStyle -> Red, 
     Background -> Directive[White, Opacity[0.5]]], 
    FrameStyle -> None, ImageMargins -> 5], {25, 0}, {Center, 
    Bottom}], AxesStyle -> Red]
```

[image]

OK. That's not so bad. But why margins are so big?

```
Plot[Sin[100 x], {x, 0, 50}, PlotStyle -> Black, 
 Epilog -> 
  Inset[Framed[
    Framed[Style[111, 30, Red], FrameStyle -> Red, 
     Background -> Directive[White, Opacity[0.5]]], 
    FrameStyle -> Green, ImageMargins -> 5], {25, 0}, {Center, 
    Bottom}], AxesStyle -> Red]
```

[image]

Oh... That's because we have some padding inside of our frame. And how can I zero this padding?

So what can I do to make what I want? I can't understand why second example didn't work. But I want to see the picture as if it worked.

Sorry if i'm so newbie in WM.
Thx.

Comment: Pardon me, what is the goal to look like?  Somehow I became confused by your examples rather than understanding better.  Possibly you want this?: `Plot[Sin[100 x], {x, 0, 50}, PlotStyle -> Black, 
 Epilog -> Inset[
   Framed[Style[111, 30, Red], FrameStyle -> Red, 
    Background -> Directive[White, Opacity[0.5]]], {25, 0}, {Center, -1.2}], 
 AxesStyle -> Red]`

Comment: Looks like YES, but, NO. I can't use OPOS to make equal margins, because of different size of text inside this Epilog... I have dynamic plots so it's really hard. I can't explain, but this is too hard to calculate all coordinates in all different situations. It's easily to use 1 exact coordinate+margin, instead of two exact pos+opos. So I want margins to work or set paddings of second framed to zero somehow...

Comment: I may need to see your animation to understand your requirements, but my *best guess* is: `Plot[Sin[100 x], {x, 0, 50}, PlotStyle -> Black, 
 Epilog -> Inset[
   Framed[Style[111, 30, Red], FrameStyle -> Red, 
    Background -> Directive[White, Opacity[0.5]]], 
   Offset[{0, 5}, {25, 0}], {Center, Bottom}], AxesStyle -> Red]` -- this keeps the Framed expression offset from zero by a fixed absolute distance.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, Thx. That works better for me. I need to change sign +/-5 in some cases, that make this solution some complicated, but it works almost like margin, like I want. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a bug. Try for example this modified version of @Mr.Wizard's suggestion:

```
Graphics[Inset[
  Framed[Style[111, 30, Red], FrameStyle -> Red, 
   Background -> Directive[White, Opacity[0.5]], 
   ImageMargins -> 70], {25, 0}, {Center, -1.2}], Background -> Black]
```

[image]

On Mac OS X, this screen shot shows that the notebook initially displays a background in the wrong position. But as soon as I scroll the page, the background disappears. It's also absent in an exported `PNG`. But the upshot is that the background should be rendered. It works as long as you don't include the `ImageMargins` option in `Framed`.

To address the spacings issue in your last example, you may want to use `FrameMargins` with a negative value.